# Premiere can't import youtube-dl MP4 file

Tags: premiere, youtube

Any idea why I can't import this MP4 file into Premiere?
It is downloaded from YouTube using youtube-dl.
Format details below:
`401          mp4        3840x2160  2160p 18468k , av01.0.12M.08, 25fps, video only, 91.85MiB`

The error is:
[image: screenshot]

What's the right command structure to get 4K MP4 files from youtube-dl preferably with audio as well, that Premiere on a Mac can play?